# Is the intersection of a relation that is antisymmetric and a relation that is not antisymmetric, antisymmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

Given a binary relation R,S on set A, assume that R is anti-symmetric.  Show R intersection S is anti-symmetric.

I started this proof by stating the definition of anti-symmetric with R which is 
$$ ∀a∀b(((a, b) ∈ R ∧ (b, a) ∈ R) → (a = b))$$  I know the basic idea that since R does not have any elements that make it not anti-symmetric, (i.e. for any $(a,b) ∈ R$ (b,a) is not an element of R), any set $R ∩ S$ will not include elements that would make R not anti-symmetric because elements of the intersections have to include both sets.  Because those same elements that would make R not antisymmetric any are not included in R, they would not be in $R ∩ S$.  Even if S was not antisymmetric and it had elements (a,b) and (b, a) where a does not equal b, and (a,b) is common with R, $R ∩ S$ would not have have (b,a) thus making it antisymmetric.  I know these things but I do not know how to write them into a formal proof.  I am stuck at this.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could also accept these suitable answers : [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525574), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525974),  [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526114),  [(4)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535862),  [(5)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538899),  [(6)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781924),  [(7)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800403),  [(8)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780220). Many thanks :-)!

Comment: And maybe these one: [(9)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805161), if you like it ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best if you write down the property that $R\cap S$ must satisfy. You want to prove that $R\cap S$ is antisymmetric, so you want to show that

$$\forall a,b:((a,b)\in R\cap S \land (b,a)\in R\cap S\implies (a=b))$$

Now, you prove this claim like any other claim starting with $\forall$:

> Let $a,b$ be such that $(a,b)\in R\cap S \land (b,a)\in R\cap S$. *Something something something* Therefore, $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusing thing is trying to look at relation $S$ separately. Suppose we use a new letter $T$ for the intersection $R \cap S.$ Then if $(a,b)$ is in $T$ and also $(b,a)$ is in $T,$ it follows that both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in $R$ because $T \subseteq R,$ because $T=R \cap S.$ From this, because $R$ is antisymmetric, we arrive at $a=b.$ Thus $T$ is antisymmetric as desired.